# Strange change of code in VS2015

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I do not understand the behavior of Visual Studio 2015 Professional.
In a Winforms Designer I write this code:

```
this.btC.Image = dllres.Properties.Resources.find;
```

Unless, recompile and I find this other code:

```
this.btC.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btC.Image")));
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you changing this in the `.Designer.cs` file ? The code there is generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, I change the Image Resource because the image are in a external dll and can not selected from ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The winforms designer internally uses something called `Global Objects`. Those work for, among other things, assigning project resources to image properties without converting them to a local form resource (in the yourForm.resx file).

If you write that code by hand, the designer won't know it's a global object (global objects get assigned by the designer using the visual studio's `IReferenceService` service provider), and will just save the assigned image into the form's local resources, and change the code to what you are seeing upon serializing again.

So you either assign the resource using the designer (the resource picker dialog), or, as the comments in the generated (`.Designer.cs`) file say, do not modify that file, and assign it on the form's constructor, right after `InitializeComponent()`